# Which event endpoint should each device send a StateReport/ChangeReport to?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, event-gateway

I built an Alexa skill and it worked on multiple regions with our light devices.

[As we know](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/send-events-to-the-alexa-event-gateway.html), while the state of a device changes, our server should send a ChangeReport event to Alexa, and there are 3 endpoints for each region:

- North America: https://api.amazonalexa.com/v3/events
- Europe: https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com/v3/events
- Far East: https://api.fe.amazonalexa.com/v3/events

I'm confused cause I don't know each device bought by which region's user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can fix it by recording customers's region when they're discovering devices.

As we know, each region linked to a lambda function, do as these two steps:

- Add an environment parameter which can define its region to lambda function, such as `locale = eu`
- Write the locale parameter to DB whenever customers discovery their devices in your lambda function, it happens when they're refreshing their Alexa APP
- According to this, we know which endpoint we need to send a ChangeReport event to